# How to bind tomcat 7 to ipv6

Tags: tomcat7, ipv6

I am trying to bind apache-tomcat-7.0.77 to my local link ipv6 address. Please note that I am working on windows 10 pro.

I have done below -

[1] At first I simply initiallized the server with start command and tried to hit the tomcat's manager page using my local link address ([ipv6]:8080/manager/html), but it didnt work.

[2] As a workaround,

[2.a] I have added a configuration in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file for a new hostname and my local link address like this -- `[my local link address]   rahul`

[2.b] Updated the tomcat's server.xml, with a new address attribute ---

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" address="<my local link address>"/>
```

[2.c] Now when I hit the url - `http://rahul:8080/manager/html`, I am able to reach to manager page. But it is still not working with url -- `http://[ipv6 add]:8080/manager/html`

Also command -

```
`netstat -an | find "8080"`
```

giving me output --->

```
`TCP    [<my local link ipv6 add>]:8080  [::]:0`
```

That means tomcat is actually listening to my local link ipv6 address.

This approach is working but the only problem with this approach is that I have to mention the address in server.xml

Please help me by suggesting the way through which I can bind the tomcat 7 to ipv6 on windows machine without specifying address attribute in server.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of times devices with multiple "up" interfaces will have issues connecting to Link-Local addresses since the prefix is the same across all interfaces. For instance, if you have WiFi turned on as well as a wired link, your OS probably doesn't know which interface to send the Link-Local traffic out. I came across this with nMap a while back and the solution was to add "%eth0" at the end when scanning a Link-Local host. The reason I bring this up (even though you didn't ask about nMap) is just to let you know how this works.

Replace %eth0 with the actual interface ID of one of your interfaces and the Link-Local address with your own:

```
http://[fe80::bad:c0de%eth0]:8080/manager/html
```

Internet Explorer needs to escape the value so preface it with `25` so it looks like this:

```
http://[fe80::bad:c0de%257]:8080/manager/html
```

I just found this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740593(v=vs.85).aspx which shows exactly what to do with Windows.

**Edit**: I just re-read what you asked and noticed that this is about binding Tomcat specifically, not just accessing a page over Link-Local.

From what I can gather, so long as the server entry has `address="::"` then it should bind to all IPv4 and all IPv6. With this, your `netstat -na | find "8080"` should have the Tomcat server listening on all IP addresses (including Link-Local). Then, use what I suggested above to browse to the Link-Local address to test it.